# Show every qr code scan result as listview in another activity

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, arraylist, qr-code

I am making a scanner where scan result will be saved in another activity. So, i used intent putextra in scanner activity & string getextra in another activity. In another activity, scan result will be displayed in listview.. So i have declared an arraylist for strings. First result is coming in another activity without problem. But when second result comes, the first result is replaced. I want to show every result in listview as like history. What I need to do?? Please help..

Comment: Do you store your data in any storage?

Answer (score 0):

When You scan QR code scan time and Navigate to result activity, it means all the variable of Result Activity are initialized again and store updated one, that's why previous entries are not showing.

- So You can use shared Preference for this, Store array list in string Shared Preference, and get same array list on Result Activity
- You can declare Array List as static variable